# Cosets of the subgroup $(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question originates from Chapter 13, B5 of the 2nd edition of [A Book of Abstract Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486474178) by Charles C. Pinter.

> Describe the cosets of the subgroup $H = \{(x,y): x=y\}$ of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my attempt:

> Let $C_r = \{(x, x+r): x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> All the cosets of the subgroup $H$ can be described as $C = \{C_r: r\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{H\}$.

Does this look reasonable?

Based on the feedback so far, here is a simpler representation:

> $C = \{C_r = H + (0,r): r\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: $C_0 = H$, so you can write $C = \{C_r:r\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Write $C_r = (0,r)+H$, they are all cosets.

Comment: Yes, that's good. Note that your cosets actually form a group ($R\times R$ is abelian, so $H$ is normal) and this group is isomorphic to $R$

Comment: $\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Your $C_{r}$ is not written correctly as $C_r = \{(x, x+r): x, r \in \mathbb{R}\}$, because as it stands it is just the whole group $\R \times \R$. Rather, for each $r \in \R$ write as suggested in another comment $C_{r} = (0, r) + H = \Set{(x, x + r) : x \in \R }$.

Comment: How about:

Let $C_r = \{(x, x+r): x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$ 

?  Will change the original post.  Thanks!